# OpenCV mass center point

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, measurement

I found the mass center of an irregular shape, but now I need to compute the distance to any given point.
I understand that the mc is a vector of points, but how can I find the coordinates of mc so I can calculate the distance between the mass center and some other point.Thanks

```
vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 );
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? It looks like your code is correct. Are you asking how to access the x and y coordinates, or whether your calculation is correct?

Comment: @Felipe I understand the question in the following way: "The code you show is an initialization of the vector of points mc, of which then you have to find the center of mass (barycenter), so that you compute the distance of any given point to this barycenter." Please provide additional clarification if necessary.

Comment: Of course, sorry. My code works well, in my case I have one contour (At least is expected one contour), how can I access the coordinates of the mass center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should get the point by index. Let :

```
int size = contours.size();
```

The indices are: `i = 0 ... size` . The point at index `i` is

```
mc[i];
```

The coordinates of that point can be reached by:

```
float xCoor = mc[i].x;
float yCoor = mc[i].y;
```

Of course you can read those values in a loop from `i = 0 to size` if you want to read all the coordinates of all the `mc` points.

**Edit:**
I assumed that you knew how to find the mass center, and was just asking how to get the coordinates. But if you want to get mass center and the distance from mass center to some other point then you could do the following:

```
float distance;
float totalX=0.0, totalY=0.0;    
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    totalX+=mc[i].x;
    totalY+=mc[i].y;
}

Point2f massCenter(totalX/size, totalY/size); // condition: size != 0
Point2F someOtherPoint(someXVal, someYVal);

distance = massCenter.distance(someOtherPoint);
```

is the distance from mass center to some other point.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect solution ... elegant.

Answer (score 1):

`mc[i].x` and `mc[i].y` are the x and y coordinates of the point of index i.

To compute the center of mass:

```
cv::Point2f baricenter(0,0);
for( int i = 0; i < mc.size(); i++ )
    barycenter += mc[i];
barycenter.x /= mc.size();
barycenter.y /= mc.size();
```

Check that you have at least one point in your vector.

Comment: The question is: "how can I find the coordinates of mc so I can calculate the distance between the mass center and some other point."

Comment: @erolyeniaras That's how I understand your question: "The code you show seems an initialization of the vector of points `mc`, of which then you have to find the center of mass (barycenter), so that you compute the distance of any given point to this barycenter." Please provide some clarification

Comment: I am a bit confused if he asks for how to calculate the coordinates of mass center or how to get (read) the coordinates of the mass center.

Comment: Ah, sorry, *his* question :) Yes, it's not very clear.

Comment: I understood, I can read the mass center coordinates per index! thanks